# Dynamic key name in rsyslog action

Tags: logging, redis, rsyslog

I am trying to send all the logs on my system to a redis database. For that I 
have the following configurations in a file "/etc/rsyslog.d/redis.conf".
I followed the instructions from [here](http://taotetek.github.io/oldschool.systems/post/omhiredis/) using the queue mode. Following
is the configuration that I have :

```
module(load="omhiredis")

action(
  name="push_redis"
  type="omhiredis"
  mode="queue"
  key="testqueue"
)
```

Problem :
The above configuration writes the logs to redis database but the "key" for
for all the logs remains same i.e. "testqueue".

```
Expected Output :
```

I want, when a program logs, a new key should be created in redis which is same as
the name of the program. Then it will be possible for me to check logs of
every program separately.

```
Attempts :
```

I tried using filters like the following :

```
if $programname == 'logger' then {
  action(
      name="push_redis"
      type="omhiredis"
      mode="queue"
      key="logger"
    )
}
```

But then I will have to write a filter for every program, which is possible
but not an acceptable solution.

```
Is there any way to create a key dynamically when a program logs into redis ?
```

Thankyou for taking time to read the question.

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved using *dynakey* parameter on 8.23 https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog/pull/1218.

Theorically it's also possible to use *mode="template"*, but it doesn't work properly yet when message contains spaces.